# Mongodb Auto Updating Field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have a field in my mongodb document called "Age" and I wanted to know if there is any way that every year, on users birthdate, the field would auto-increment. Is it possible? if so, What is the easiest way to do this? else, what is recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule a cron task or any other applicative code that would query your database for the relevant users and update their age.
I strongly advise against it though.

The age property is a computation on the date of birth given the current time.
You'd like to keep it that way, and compute it on the fly:

1. Having two fields, where one can be computed from the other is redundant and error prone.
2. The action itself is wasteful in terms of space and data access.
3. The value of age property depends on the applicative logic and in some cases you might want to consider a non integer date or rouding differently.

My suggestion, simply compute the age base on the birth date whenever you need it, and make all database queries using the birthdate field.

Good luck

Eyal

Comment: I will delete the "age" field and stick to only using the "birthdate" one, thank you very much for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing (autoupdate) in MongoDB. It must be done with application or script. You can make f.ex. cronjob what update once day, just after midnight all "Age" fields for documents where users DOB is on that day.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such field, but it can be done. There is a nice tutorial from MongoDB [Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing it like that, mongoose has a feature called virtual fields, which lets you define a field that doesn't exist in the database, but get computed on the fly.

To define a virtual field in mongoose:

```js
userSchema.virtual('age').get(function () {
  const birthdate = this.birthdate // $this is the document in the db.
  const today = Date.now()
  // ..etc and calculate the age then don't forget to return the result
  return age
})
```

Now, when someone asks for the document, mongoose will send the age field along with the response.

And remember, this doesn't exist in the database, it is only going to be in the response.

---

Now, if you want to search by the age, you can't search by the age field directly, because it doesn't exist in the database, so you can't do something like:

```js
UserModel.find({ age: { $gt: 10 } })
```

Instead, you should re-compute it again like so:

```js
UserModel.find({ birthday: { $gt: 2012  } }) // for example
```

If you want to query it, you can define a middleware for that,

```js
userSchema.pre(^/find/, function(next){
  const query = this // $this is the queryObj, not the document, be aware.
  // check if query has the $age prop, then add a query on top of that, idk how.
  next() // don't forget to call next
})
```